# DIV not taking 100% viewport height

Tags: html, css

As you can see on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYfXD/) I try to get a DIV with a back ground picture taking 100% of the viewport head (the goal is to achieve [something like this](https://medium.com/web-design-tutorials/aeb72baf1755))

Unfortunately I've tried various things without success (i.e. change the height of element-1 to 100%, the method described [here](http://www.minimit.com/demos/perfect-responsive-fullscreen-backgrounds-jquery), etc.).
What is the issue?

Many thanks

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="element element-1"></div>
    <div class="article-titles">
      <h1 class="title">Head Text</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Sub-head text</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
.element {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.element-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
  height: 600px; <-- I've tried to change this to 100% but without success
  border-top: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/650x450');
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the height of `.element-1` to 100% is only going to heighten it to 100% of the height of the parent element.

If you want the background image to cover the entire viewport I would attach it to `<body>` or `<html>`.

If you attach it to `<html>` it will cover the entire viewport and you won't have to (and should not in fact) set a `height` attribute on it.

Comment: Apply html,body{height: 100%}

Answer (score 0):

If backward compatibility is not one of the things you seek, you [can use viewport units](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units).

Giving the `.element-1` height `100vh` makes the div take 100% of viewport (visible area)'s height.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYfXD/1/).

Comment: Thanks Prasanth. Unfortunately that does not seem to work on the updated fiddle (I tried on safari latest version)